# Airflow: Zoom in Sub Dag button in customized SubDagOperator

Tags: airflow

I've designed a customized `SubDagOperator`. Everything works fine except that the "Zoom in Sub Dag" button doesn't appear. It seems that if the airflow UI doesn't recognise the task as a subdagoperator itself the button is not shown. I've tried to override the `task_type` property, as it was mentioned in and old issue, but it doesn't work for me. Do you know if it's possible to see the button with customized SubDagOperators?

Airflow version: 1.10.12

Here is my try:

```py
class EmrSubdagOperator(SubDagOperator):
  template_fields = ()
  template_ext = ()
  


  @apply_defaults
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    dag = kwargs.get('dag')
    task_id = kwargs.get('task_id')
    spark_steps = kwargs.get('spark_steps')
    job_flow_overrides = kwargs.get('job_flow_overrides')

    subdag = DAG(
        '{}.{}'.format(dag.dag_id, task_id),
        schedule_interval=dag.schedule_interval,
        start_date=dag.start_date
        )

    cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        dag=subdag,
        task_id='create_job_flow',
        job_flow_overrides=job_flow_overrides
    )

    step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        dag=subdag,
        task_id='add_steps',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=spark_steps,
    )
    
    #Check if the last step is completed, skipped or terminated
    last_step = len(spark_steps) - 1 
    step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
        dag=subdag,
        task_id='watch_step',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='add_steps', key='return_value')[" + str(last_step) +"]}}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    )

    cluster_checker = EmrJobFlowSensor(
        dag=subdag,
        task_id='watch_cluster',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    )
    
    
    super(EmrSubdagOperator, self).__init__(subdag=subdag, *args, **kwargs)
    self.spark_steps = spark_steps
    self.job_flow_overrides = job_flow_overrides

  @property
  def task_type(self):
      return 'SubDagOperator'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I resolved that, doing:

```
class DynamicTasksOperator(SubDagOperator):
 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self._task_type = 'SubDagOperator'

 @property
 def task_type(self):
    return self._task_type
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following changes in the **airflow.cfg** and its working for me now.

```
store_serialized_dags = False
store_dag_code = False
```